# is blender 2.83.4 still in development?

Tags: versions

My blender 2.8 got extremely corrupt and so I was planning on downloading the latest fully developed blender version so there are no bugs. What is the current fully developed blender version?

Comment: Also I can't reinstall 2.8 because it still gets the se error

Comment: Are you sure you fully removed it in the first place?

Comment: Yes. I did fully remove it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You should make sure you are not sourcing your blender downloads from some corrupt source and make sure you are sourcing it from the proper site.

Comment: Yes I am sourcing it from the proper site.